# Replacing an element using jquery ui with drag and drop doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Using the latest jQuery UI, the drag and drop function doesn't work properly, when moving elements from one list to another. I want to drag elements from one list to another and replace the drooped element with another one, the problem is that jquery UI replaces the element but it moves it to the bottom of the list, it doesn't keep it to the position where it was dropped.

```
    <head>
    <style>
    #list1{

        float:left;
        width: 200px;
        margin-right: 20px;
    }
    #list2{

        float:left;
        width: 200px;
    }    
    .element1{
        line-height:25px;
         width: 200px;
        margin-bottom:5px;
        margin-top:5px;
        background-color:#ededed;

    }
    .element2{
        line-height:25px;
         width: 200px;
        margin-bottom:5px;
        margin-top:5px;
        background-color:#ffeded;

    }  
    .highlight{
        border: 1px dashed #999999;
        color: #333333;
        height: 25px;
        background-color: #faffd6;

    }    
    </style>    
    </head>
    <body class="">

    <div id="wrapper">
       <div id="list1">
       <div class="element1">Element 1</div>
       <div class="element1">Element 2</div> 
       <div class="element1">Element 3</div>    
       <div class="element1">Element 4</div>    
       <div class="element1">Element 5</div>    
       <div class="element1">Element 6</div>    
       </div>   

       <div id="list2">
       <div class="element2">Element 1</div>
       <div class="element2">Element 2</div> 
       <div class="element2">Element 3</div>    
       <div class="element2">Element 4</div>    
       <div class="element2">Element 5</div>    
       <div class="element2">Element 6</div>    
       </div>   

    </div>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    $(window).load(function () {


        $("#list1").sortable({
        revert: true,
         placeholder: "highlight",

        });

        $("#list2").sortable({
        revert: true,
         placeholder: "highlight",

        });



        $( ".element1" ).draggable({
          connectToSortable: "#list2",
          revert: "invalid",  
        stop: function( event, ui ) {

         $(this).replaceWith('<div class="element1">Element 99</div>');

        }
        });


    });    
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you got is that you have two different events and you catch only one of them.

1. You drag item from gray-list and place it inside the pink-list, your highlight element is shown and then you drop it. This is your **problematic** usage.
2. You grad item from gray-list and place it inside the pink-list, your highlight element is shown, then you take your dragged element outside of that list (you still have the margin of the new list-item, but the highlighted element is not there) and you drop it. This scenario is all good.

Your problem is that on the first scenario the dragged element position (DOM-wise) is the last element of the list, and when you drop it what happen is that you get animation to put it in the correct position (where the highlight element is places) and then there is a switch. If you change that the function that should change between those elements will not know which elements to switch.

The way to fix this issue is to go to the "droppable" element - the list you put your item in. use the `deactivate` event of the `sortable` (`#list2`) to run anything you want **after** the element was placed in the right place.

```
$("#list2").sortable({
    revert: true,
    placeholder: "highlight",
    deactivate: function(event, ui) {
        $(ui.item).replaceWith('<div class="element1">Element 99</div>');
    }
});
```

Note the usage of `event.toElement` and not `this`, since `this` in the current scope is the list element and not the dragged element. Don't forget to remove the code of the `stop` event from your draggable element.

Comment: The problem with using toElement is that it doesn't work on internet explorer

Comment: You are correct. Changed from toElement to use `ui.item`, which is the current item we dropped.